# Need help rearranging this code (for Wordpress single.php)

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, wordpress

I need help with rearranging the code in my single.php file for my premium theme on Wordpress.

Currently, posts on my Wordpress site feature a Facebook comment box in the Related Posts section, with the default Wordpress comment box under the Leave A Comment section. I would like to either remove the default Wordpress comment box completely and replace it with the Facebook one (so that it is under the Leave A Comment heading), or I would like to have both the Facebook and Wordpress comment boxes under the Leave A Comment heading, with the Facebook one appearing on top.

I was not able to insert the entire single.php file code into Stack Overflow (as I seen that some of the code is coming up unformatted due to Stack Overflow limitations, I believe), so here's a [download link](http://www.sharebeast.com/vkmpo0790me2) to download the .php from ShareBeast.

Now here's the suggestion/"hint" I received from the theme's developer about this matter.

> Go to single.php Go to line 83
>
> This code is FB: if($bd_data['post_fb_comments_box']){
>                               ?>
>                               
>                               (function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;  js =
>   d.createElement(s); js.id = id;  js.src =
>   "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"; 
>   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script',
>   'facebook-jssdk'));
>                               '
>   ."\n";
>                           }
>
> ==================
>
> This code is wordpress:
>
> if($bd_data['post_comments_box']){
>                               wp_reset_query(); comments_template();
>                           }

Here's an [example of my a post on my site](http://theoriginalsociety.com/luke-christopher-murder-block/) that uses both comment boxes.

If anyone could rearrange the code as I described and either upload the .php and send me a link to it or post it here I guess, that would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `add_filter( 'comment_form_field_comment', 'function_name' ); function function_name($field) {....return $field;}`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not very experienced in HTML... Can you be specific, using layman's terms if possible?

Comment: use add_filter hook for 'comment_form_field_comment', it replace the default comment form to custom form

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress, comment_form_field_comment hook used to change the default comment form behavior or custom form. And we initialize the function in 'init' hook to load on wordpress initially

In function.php

```
add_action('init', 'custom_comment_form');

function custom_comment_form() {
   add_filter( 'comment_form_field_comment', 'facebook_comment_form' );
}

function facebook_comment_form( $field ) {
   //your facebook comment form, stored in $field variable

   return $field;
}
```